# How welcome.JSP file be called welcoming user by taking name from index.html page?

Tags: html, jsp

I am struggling with something really basic. I have created a index.jsp file

```
<html>  
<body>  
<form action="welcome.jsp">  
<input type="text" name="uname">  
<input type="submit" value="go"><br/>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

And a welcome.jsp page

```
<html>  
<body>  
<%  
String name=request.getParameter("uname");  
out.print("welcome "+name);  
%>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

When I try to run the application containing just these two files. Then, I get the index.html page generated fine. However, once I put the user name and press submit then it gives 404 error.

Comment: What server are you running on? What is the error message from server log?

Comment: @DJ. I am using Tomcat server and I am getting 404 error. Both the above page are running fine separately though when i run the dynamic web project then index.jsp runs fine. I put the user name and submit but the welcome page gives error 404.

Comment: @DJ. It started working fine.

Comment: What did you do to get it working? Can you wrote it down as an answer so other can learn from this?